# fail to minify asapqueue while building electron

Tags: reactjs, electron, minify, react-dnd

My project is using react ver 16.13.0 and electronNet ver 13.5.1. Recently I added some plugin for my project: react-dnd (11.1.3) and react-dnd-html5-backend (16.0.1). Everything is working fine in the development stage, till the moment I build my electron application with electronize command, I got an error:

```
  Creating an optimized production build...
  Failed to compile.

  Failed to minify the code from this file:

        ./node_modules/@react-dnd/asap/dist/cjs/AsapQueue.js:6
```

I tried to click on the read more link (bit.ly/2tRViJ9), but I cant find any information. I tried to remove all node modules and reinstall, but I still get the same error. Can anyone help on this?